# Proxy server config help on Raspbian Jessie (can't browse internet in chromium)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to configure a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie to use our organisation's proxy server to connect to the internet.

So far I'm not having any luck browsing the internet in chromium. (I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`)

I've given the device a static IP address and can ping the router and www.google.com so I think I've configured the IP and DNS settings correctly.

I've added the following to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
export http_proxy="http://myproxy:myport/"
export https_proxy="http://myproxy:myport/"
```

...and rebooted the device but I'm getting timeout errors on chromium.

Any suggestions?